# Should this be called a torus segment or torus sector?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Is there an accepted term to refer to portions of a torus as represented in magenta and blue in the picture at the address below?

http://news.povray.org/povray.binaries.images/attachment/%3C48dae480@news.povray.org%3E/pie_torus.good.png

Would you call this a 'segment'? Or a 'sector', roughly following the terminology for circles?

Thanks!